# HazelCast: SqlPredicate issue

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am new to using HazelCast. I have a map of key and value, value being a list of objects. I am trying to use SqlPredicate on the map to filter the values.
Code Snippet:

```
private void testHazelCast() {
    final Employee e1 = new Employee("A", 20, 30);
    final Employee e2 = new Employee("C", 25, 45);
    final Employee e3 = new Employee("B", 30, 35);
    final Employee e4 = new Employee("F", 35, 30);
    final Employee e5 = new Employee("E", 40, 40);
    final Employee e6 = new Employee(null, 40, 20);
    final Employee e7 = new Employee("F", 60, 55);

    List<Employee> employeeList_1 = new ArrayList<Employee>() {{add(e1);add(e2);}};
    List<Employee> employeeList_2 = new ArrayList<Employee>() {{add(e3);add(e4);add(e7);}};
    List<Employee> employeeList_3 = new ArrayList<Employee>() {{add(e5);}};
    List<Employee> employeeList_4 = new ArrayList<Employee>() {{add(e6);}};
    IMap<Integer, List<Employee>> map = hazelcast.getMap("employee");
    map.put(1, employeeList_1);
    map.put(2, employeeList_2);
    map.put(3, employeeList_3);
    map.put(4, employeeList_4);

    // EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
    // Predicate predicate_1 = e.get("name").equal("A");
    Predicate predicate = new SqlPredicate("name = A");
    Set<List<Employee>> employeeSet = (Set<List<Employee>>) map.values(predicate_1);
}

class Employee implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int age;
    int weight;

    public Employee(String name, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Name: " + name + ", ");
        sb.append("Age: " + age + ", ");
        sb.append("Weight: " + weight);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Employee employee = (Employee) o;

        if (age != employee.age) return false;
        if (weight != employee.weight) return false;
        if (!name.equals(employee.name)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + weight;
        return result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

While executing the above code, I am getting an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'name' on class 'class java.util.ArrayList'

Could you somebody let me know what exactly I am doing wrong. I understand that it's trying to find the "name" element in the List class.
Is there anyway that I can use SqlPredicate to filter the values ?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

A predicat is executed on each value of a map. In your example, your map has a Collection of Employee as values, so the predicat is executed on this collection.

Your predicat evaluate to "a collection with name = A" : This is not valid, because a collection doesn't have a name.

In Hazelcast 3.6, you have a notion of 'custom attribute' and ValueExtractor. You can :

1. Create a class, which own a collection of employee
2. Link this class to a ValueExtractor which collect the names of each employe in a custom attribute 'name'

see: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-attributes

Moreover, having a map of collection is not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks Jeremie. I was using hazelcast 3.4, but I have now upgraded it to 3.6. I am trying to write a little test class using ValueExtractot but haven't progressed much. Could you please just edit your answer explain with code snippet as to how to go about it.